# Puzzled by a effect of "dpichanger" (by a user of my app), seek advice on how to deal with it

Tags: android, dpi

I'm working on the Android port of an app called RoadMap. Works on my smartphone and on two tablets I tried.
A user reports that on his tablet, RoadMap doesn't use up the full screen.

Turns out he changed the DPI with "DPIChanger" from 160 to 240. His physical tablet is a Kindle Fire, but with CM7 software. This device has 1024x600 pixels, like one of my own.

A debugging line on my own tablet shows (as it should) :

> E/RoadMap ( 9574): Display dpi 160 (x 159.5681 y 160.42105) pixels x
>   1024 y 600

but on the user's tablet it says

> 01-29 12:51:18.968  5753  5753 E RoadMap : Display dpi 240 (x
>   164.61772 y 165.65218) pixels x 480 y 320

Is there a way for me to figure out screen size and add that to my app, or is the effect of DPIChanger just plain wrong and I shouldn't deal with such situations ?